# Partitioning a Matrix

Tags: algorithm

Given an `N x N` matrix, where `N <= 25`, and each cell has a positive integer value, how can you partition it with at most K lines (with straight up/down lines or straight left/right lines [note: they have to extend from one side to the other]) so that the maximum value group (as determined by the partitions) is minimum?

For example, given the following matrix

```
1 1 2
1 1 2 
2 2 4
```

and we are allowed to use 2 lines to partition it, we should draw a line between column 2 and 3, as well as a line between rows 2 and 3, which gives the minimized maximum value, 4.

My first thought would be a bitmask representing the state of each lines, with 2 integers to represent it. However, this is too slow. I think the complexity is `O(2^(2N))`Maybe you could solve it for the rows, then solve it for the columns?

Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Here is the problem after I googled it: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X94001546

another paper: http://cis.poly.edu/suel/papers/pxp.pdf

I'm trying to read that^

Comment: What do you mean by maximum value group

Comment: You mean the sum of the cells in each of the four groups?

Comment: There can be at most K lines drawn (K is less than `2N - 2`)

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal If you partition according to the lines drawn, and sum up the values in each of the blocks you created, you take the maximum sum out of all the blocks. You want to minimize this number.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X94001546

Comment: For `N <= 25`, what about **bruteforce** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try all subsets for vertical lines, and then do dynamic programming for horizontal lines.

Let's say you have fixed the set of vertical lines as S. Denote the answer for the subproblem consisting of first K lines of matrix with fixed set of vertical lines S as D(K, S). It is then trivial to find a recurrence to solve D(K, S) with subproblems of smaller size.

Overall complexity should be O(2^N * N^2) if you precompute the sizes of each submatrix in the beginning.